# how to use optional url parameters with NestjS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, fastify

I'm trying to replace our current backend service using Nestjs library, 
however, I want to create a route with 2 optional parameters in the URL something like :

`/route/:param1/config/:OptionalParam3?/:OptionalParam3?`

that means the route should catch :

1. `route/aa/config`
2. `route/aa/config/bb`
3. `route/aa/config/bb/cc`

how can I achieve that, I have tried to use `?` and `()` but it's not working well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Router params name should be unique. The correct route path is:

Existing one is:

```
/route/:param1/config/:OptionalParam3?/:OptionalParam3?
```

Correction:

```
/route/:param1/config/:OptionalParam3?/:OptionalParam4?
```

Opinion: You can use query params if the params are optional. It is never a good idea to create optional param routes (disagreements agreed). Both serve the same purpose, but having them as the query params makes it more understandable for debugging and fellow developers.

Comment: `@Vinayak Sarawagi` your approach makes sense. But for the sake of url readability for service users sometimes it worth to keep longer url, but with a short option

Comment: not working for me.. not sure why getting the 404 Error..
my URL: 
resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2?

Comment: figured another way as solution used something like this in NestJS
@Delete([
'resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2',
'resource1/:id1/resource2'
])

Comment: This approach is correct but doesn't consider the project is using NestJS, which offers a lot more readability

Answer (score 23):

If you are looking for how to annotate an optional query parameter, you can do it like so:

```
@ApiQuery({
  name: "myParam",
  type: String,
  description: "A parameter. Optional",
  required: false
})
async myEndpoint(
  @Query("myParam") myParam?: string
): Promise<blah> { 
  [...] 
}
```

Comment: This worked to me, but I could make it work with a custom path.

Comment: I tried this way but the api always returned 200 status without any content

Comment: The only way that worked for me in Swagger.

Comment: https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/30#issuecomment-1250550921

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by using `@Query` decorator as below:

Here is my controller:

```
@Get()
async getAll(@Query('someParameter') someParameter?: number) {
  return this.service.getAll(someParameter);
}
```

Here is my client (Angular) service:

```
getAll(someParameter?: number) {
  return this.http.get(`apiUrl/controllerAddress?someParameter=${someParameter}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but, you can also try this in your controller:

```
@Get()
  async getExample(
    @Query('param_name') param_name?: string,
    @Query('param_name2') param_name2?: string,
  ): Promise<JSON> {
    const params = {
      param_name,
      param_name2,
    };

    return this.appService.getExampleService(params);
  }
}
```

I'm using an interface to validate the type of each param, but can pass both of the params inside the getExampleService like "(param_name, param_name2)"

Comment: This will only make the function argument optional.

Comment: I thought that was the point of the question

Answer (score -2):

You can use this structure:

-route
-aa
-config
-[[...id]].js

It will work for the routes :
route/aa/config/{anything}